# Binary Search function using recursion returning 'None'

Tags: binary-search

i have written code for Binary Search.It prints mid value but does not return the same while exiting the function.

```
def binarysearch(array,low,high,key):
  mid=(low+high)//2
  if array[mid]==key:
    print ('arrar[mid]: ',array[mid],'mid= ', mid)
     return mid
  elif key> array[mid]:
    binarysearch(array, low+1, high,key)
  elif key<array[mid]:
    binarysearch(array,low,mid-1,key)
  else:
    return -1


data=[1,2,3,4,5]
result=binarysearch(data,0,5,5)
print('result=',result)
```

output:

```
 arrar[mid]: 5 mid =4
 result=None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
elif key> array[mid]:
binarysearch(array, low+1, high,key)
```

should be

```
elif key> array[mid]:
binarysearch(array, mid, high,key)
```

Comment: yes, i changed the code accordingly. But the problem here is that the function returns 'None' for     " if array[mid]==key:  
                      print ('arrar[mid]: ',array[mid],'mid= ', mid)
                     return mid " but Prints the correct position of the Key i am searching.

Comment: That's weird... What input are you using? Can you also share the whole code (in github for example)?